# Working out cyclic subgroups of $D_{8}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, dihedral-groups

I've been trying to work out the cyclic subgroups of $D_{8}$ out by hand and thought I could do it but I've run into something I don't understand.
$D_{8}$ = $\{1,r,r^{2},r^{3},s,sr,sr^{2},sr^{3}\}$
I found $\{1\}, \{1,r,r^{2},r^{3}\}, \{1,r^{2}\}$
I thought it would be the same process for $s$ but I'm confused... 
First of all there was $\{1,s\}$ which makes sense but then I tried to find the cyclic subgroup generated by $<sr>$ and got $\{1, sr, r^{2}, sr^{3}\}$ which is wrong as it should be $\{1,sr\}$ and the same applies for  $<sr^{3}>$ being $\{1,sr^{3}\}$.
For some reason $\{1,sr^{2}\}$ was still correct for $<sr^{2}>$ though. Can anyone explain?

Comment: What is your calculation for $(s r)^{2} = s r s r$?

Comment: I thought it would be $r^{2}$ because $s^{2}$ = $1$ but this must be wrong as my calculations are not correct.

Comment: You should have learned what $s r s = s^{-1} r s$ is.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti yes I understand the mistake I made now. $srsr = r^{-1}r = 1$